# Have to add Selenium jar after every pull from Git

Tags: java, git, selenium

This is likely my limited understanding of the workings of Git but I have a private remote repository that I use just for myself between 3 different machines. I'm using `Netbeans 8.0.2` with `selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar` on each machine.

If I commit a file to the remote repository from one machine and pull it down on another, I have to add the selenium jar file to the libraries folder manually each time.

Surely there's a way that I can keep my project configuration? I'm sure this is just something I haven't learned yet but would appreciate some direction or instruction.

***Any suggestions?***

Comment: [tag:Maven] is the answer.

Comment: Why do you need to install server every time? Why cant install once and leave it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is exactly what you need.

And you don't need to think which exactly jars you need to add to `lib` folder. But you need to install ***Maven*** on your different machines.

Your `pom.xml` have to include:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
  <version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Additional links:

- [How To Install Maven On Windows](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)
- [Using NetBeans with Apache Maven](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Maven)
- [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maven` to setup a central repository to configure all your repositories. 
If you donot want to use maven or donot prefer the learning curve . Commit the lib folder into GIT. You will not need to copy them every time.